# Clarification needed on 2012 Election Page

Tags: discussion

From the [election](https://serverfault.com/election) page:

> There will be a town hall chat with the candidates on Monday at 21:00
>   UTC / 4pm EST.

Since the town hall chat already happened, this should either just be deleted or perhaps have a date added and changed to past tense.

Here's a whack at some replacement verbage:

> On Monday, January 16th, a Town Hall chat was held with candidates in
>   the primary phase of the election. A [digest](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2626/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest) is now available of
>   the questions posed and the candidates' answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch.  I've updated the post with your suggested wording.